# Send file path to input tag using Selenium WebDriver doesn't work (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

I have to send file path to input:

```
<input class="hide" type="file" ... >
```

Element was found by `input.findElement(By.xpath(...))`. I checked it a lot of time. File path was checked too and existed. I send this path in this way:

```
input.sendKeys(System.getProperty("user.dir") + filePath);
```

But `sendKeys`doesn't see this path. I don't know why. Before update it works.C:\xtm\workspace\xtmintl-webdrive.\resources\file\terms_xls.xls

Does anybody know how do it by JavaScript in Java code? I tested send file path by Robot, but it sometimes crashes and it's very annoying.

Comment: P.S. Sorry for this strange path to file in my topic.

Comment: When I touch Selenium 3 years ago,  its official site said if you use sendkyes() to type  the file path into file upload element,  the file upload element muse be visible.  I'm not sure this rule still work on today. I notice you use 'hide'  class on file upload, did the hide class will  make element not visible?

Comment: Yes, I checked this element and visibility is false. I try setting element's visibility. Maybe it works.

Comment: I set visibility, but file is still "not found". I don't know why because path exists.

Comment: what is your meaning of  "file not found", is the file upload input element on page not found  or  the file on  disk you want to upload not found?

Comment: can you paste your exact piece of code?